# Issue filtering table view in javafx when I am using setCellFactory

Tags: javafx-8

Hello all I have problem filtering table view when I am using `setCellFactory`. The search working perfectly until I add the code in `setCellFactory`. I provided image about the issue. The search function was copied from code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-sorting-filtering/.
My cellFactory Fucntion:

```
    licenseExp.setCellFactory(column -> {
        return new TableCell<Vehicles, String>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                // update the item and set a custom style if necessary
                if (item != null) {



                    if(!search)
                    {
                        System.out.println("search" + search);
                    setText(item.toString());
                    }
                    try {
                        timeCheck = TimeChecker.checkExpire(DateUtil.reformatDate(this.getText()),DateUtil.newDateNormal());
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (timeCheck.equals("expired")) {
                        this.getTableRow().getStyleClass().add("expired");
                    }
                    if (timeCheck.equals("warning")) {
                        this.getTableRow().getStyleClass().add("warning");
                    }

                }
            }
        };
    });
```

My search function:

```
![// Filtering method

private void filteredData()

{
FilteredList<dispatch> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(data, p -> true);

// 2. Set the filter Predicate whenever the filter changes.

searchField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

filteredData.setPredicate(dispatch -> {

// If filter text is empty, display all Dispatchs.

if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {

return true;

}

// Compare first name and last name of every Dispatch with filter text.

String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();

if (dispatch.getDriver().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {

return true; // Filter matches driver name.

} else if (dispatch.getVehicle().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {

return true; // Filter matches vehicle plate_number.

} else if (dispatch.getDate().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {

return true; // Filter matches vehicle plate_number.

} else if (dispatch.getStatus().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {

return true; // Filter matches vehicle plate_number.

}

return false; // Does not match.

});
});
SortedList<dispatch> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filteredData);
sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(table.comparatorProperty());
table.setItems(sortedData);

}
```

[image]

Comment: looks like the cellFactory is not handling the empty state correctly (just a guess, of course, nothing more possible without you providing a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem)

Comment: What do you mean by SSCCE?

Comment: what happened when you typed the acronym into the search box of your favorite search engine ;-) Basically a small example ...

Comment: @James_D thank you so much for this. Its all working now. God bless you. Sorry I click vote twice. I just unvote it me so naive.